# Measure that has the same null sets as the lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm searching for a measure $ \mu $ in $ \mathbb{R} $ for that $\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$ and a set is a $\mu$-null-set if and only if it is a $\lambda$-null-set for the lebesgue measure $\lambda$.

The main problem are uncountable null sets like the cantor set. Cant think of a way to include those.

Comment: One thing to notice is the measure won't be translation invariant. By countable additivity, $\mu(\mathbb{R})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\mu([n,n+1])=1$; if $\mu$ is translation invariant, all intervals will have measure 0.

Comment: Good to know! Is that valid for all measures with infinite values?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow A$ and $m$ is some function defined on some subsets of $A$. Then we can "pull back" $m$ to $\mathbb{R}$, by setting $$m_f(X)=m(f[X])$$ whenever $m(f[X])$ is defined. The hope is:

> If $f$ is "nice," then $m_f$ will behave like $m$ in many ways.

In our case, the natural thing to do is look for a "nice" map $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to some measure-one set - say, $(0, 1)$ - and then hope that $\mu_f$ is an appropriate measure on $\mathbb{R}$. So:

> Can you think of any "nice" bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0, 1)$?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{e^{x}+1}$ would be a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$.
Can i use the lebesgue measure $\lambda$ as $\mu$?
Therefore $\lambda_{f}(\mathbb{R}) = \lambda(f(\mathbb{R})) = \lambda((0,1))=1$.
Because of the fact that $f$ is a continous function it is borel-measurable and therefore lebesgue-measurable?

Comment: @Erdbeer0815 Yes.

Comment: Thanks thats a beatiful way to do it